# AWS CodeDeploy with Symfony1

Tags: amazon-web-services, symfony1, aws-code-deploy

I am trying to integrate a Symfony1 application with Amazon CodeDeploy.

We build model and forms on the server during the deployment process. However, sadly, the CodeDeploy log shows the following error when running ./symfony propel:build-model within /var/app/current in the AfterInstall hook.

[Aws::CodeDeployCommand] put_host_command_complete(command_status:"Failed",diagnostics:{format:"JSON",payload:#> tokens    /var/app/current/lib/form/FormName.class.php\n[stdout]>> tokens    /var/app/current/lib/form/FormName.class.php\n[stdout]>> tokens    /var/app/current/lib/form/FormName.class.php\n[stdout]>> tokens    /var/app/current/lib/form/FormName.class.php\n[stdout]>> tokens    /var/app/current/lib/form/FormName.class.php\n[stdout]>> tokens    /var/app/current/lib/form/FormName.class.php\n[stdout]>> tokens    /var/app/current/lib/form/FormName.class.php\n[stdout]>> tokens    /var/app/current/lib/form/FormName.class.php\n[stdout]>> tokens    /var/app/current/lib/form/FormName.class.php\n[stdout]>> tokens    /var/app/current/lib/form/FormNameFormName.class.php\n[stdout]>>" ... (2248 bytes)>}...

Any pointers here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like there are some errors in your after install hook script. You can find the script output in the deployment directory under logs/scripts.log

On Linux based systems it defaults to '/opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/CodeDeploy-DEPLOYMENT-GROUP-ID/DEPLOYMENT-ID /logs/scripts.log'

On Windows systems the default is 'C:\ProgramData\Amazon\CodeDeploy-DEPLOYMENT-GROUP-ID\DEPLOYMENT-ID\logs\scripts.log'